# Python: scipy.sparse / pandas Null values in sparse matrix is being converted to large negative integer

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, null, integer-overflow

I am trying to work with scipy sparse COO matrix but I am running into weird errors with null values being converted to large negative integers. Here is what I am doing:

```
import pickle5 as pk5
from scipy import sparse
import pandas as pd

with open('some_file.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    df = pk5.load(f)
```

The original sparse df looks correct:

`df.iloc[0:5, 0:4])`:

```
 1028799.3_nuc_coding  1156994.3_nuc_coding  1156995.3_nuc_coding
0                   1.0                   NaN                   NaN
1                   NaN                   1.0                   NaN
2                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
3                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
4                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
```

Running dropna works fine so it is actually null values.

`df.iloc[0].dropna().index[:3]`

```
Index(['1028799.3_nuc_coding', '1280.11650_nuc_coding',
       '1280.11655_nuc_coding'],
      dtype='object')
```

But running any operation on it changes the NaN values to -9223372036854775808. For example here is `df.T`:

```
                                      0                    1  \
1028799.3_nuc_coding                    1 -9223372036854775808   
1156994.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808                    1   
1156995.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808   

                                        2                    3  \
1028799.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808   
1156994.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808   
1156995.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808   

                                        4  
1028799.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808  
1156994.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808  
1156995.3_nuc_coding -9223372036854775808
```

I have gotten similar errors with df.iterrows() and with coversion to coo matrix in scipy using the code above.

```
coo_mat = sparse.coo_matrix(df.values, shape=df.shape)
print(coo_mat)
```

```
(0, 0)  1
  (0, 1)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 2)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 3)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 4)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 5)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 6)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 7)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 8)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 9)    -9223372036854775808
  (0, 10)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 11)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 12)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 13)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 14)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 15)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 16)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 17)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 18)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 19)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 20)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 21)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 22)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 23)   -9223372036854775808
  (0, 24)   -9223372036854775808
  : :
```

Comment: `np.array(np.nan).astype(int)` creates that same large negative **integer**.  `np.nan` is a `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hpaulj for the hint! The problem was that my dtype was an int. So recasting it to float solves the issue. Example:

`df.iloc[0:5, 0:4].astype(float).T`

```
                          0   1   2    3  4
1028799.3_nuc_coding    1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1156994.3_nuc_coding    NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN
1156995.3_nuc_coding    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1156996.3_nuc_coding    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Similarly, other operations like iterrows and casting to coo_matrix also works as expected once the type is changed to float.